# Sums of Euler's totient function in sublinear time

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, restricted-complexity

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265114/sums-of-sum-of-divisors-in-sublinear-time).

Given a number \$n\$, Euler's totient function, \$\varphi(n)\$ is the number of integers up to \$n\$ which are coprime to \$n\$. That is, no number bigger than \$1\$ divides both of them.
For example, \$\varphi(6) = 2\$, because the only relevant numbers are \$1, 5\$. This is OEIS [A000010](https://oeis.org/A000010).

We can now define the sum of euler's totient function as \$S(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\varphi(i)}\$, the sum of \$\varphi(i)\$ for all numbers from \$1\$ to \$n\$. This is OEIS [A002088](https://oeis.org/A002088).

Your task is to calculate \$S(n)\$, **in time sublinear in \$\mathbf{n}\$,** \$o(n)\$.

### Test cases

```
10 -> 32
100 -> 3044
123 -> 4636
625 -> 118984
1000 -> 304192
1000000 (10^6) -> 303963552392
1000000000 (10^9) -> 303963551173008414
```

### Rules

- **Your complexity must be \$o(n)\$**. That is, if your algorithm takes time \$T(n)\$ for input \$n\$, you must have \$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T(n)}n = 0\$. Examples of valid time complexities are \$O(\frac n{\log(n)})\$, \$O(\sqrt n)\$, \$O(n^\frac57 \log^4(n))\$, etc.
- You can use any reasonable I/O format.
- Note that due to the limited complexity you can't take the input in unary nor output in it (because then the I/O takes \$\Omega(n)\$ time), and the challenge might be impossible in some languages.
- Your algorithm should in theory be correct for all inputs, but it's fine if it fails for some of the big test cases (due to overflow or floating-point inaccuracies, for example).
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

This is code golf, so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: @doubleunary There's a sublinear Python solution in the OEIS page

Comment: Are we allowed to assume all basic integer operations are O(1)? (even though in reality they are necessarily O(log(n)) for arbitrary-precision integers)

Comment: @pxeger No, but \$O(\log n)\$ shouldn't be problematic since all numbers involved are \$O(n^2)\$

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>121</s> <s>99</s> 98 bytes

```
⊞υＮ≔⦃⦄ηＦυＦ¬§ηι«≔ιζ≔²ε≔÷ιεδ≔⟦⟧κＷ›δ¹«≔⊕÷ιδλ¿§ηδ≧⁺×⁻λε⊖⊗§ηδζ⊞κδ≔λε≔÷ιλδ»¿κＦ⊞Ｏκι⊞υλ§≔ηι÷⁺⁻×ιιζε²»Ｉ§η⊟υ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZK9bsIwFIWlbuQZOlwx2ZKRClMlJtRIFQM0qrohhpBciIVxIv_Qqogn6cJQ1D5Tn6Z2nIgg4cW6dvzdc-7J129WpCorU3E6na1ZDx7_7u4TqwtiGUxlZc3c7laoCKXjaKI130hyODIoXLkuFRBLod7npSETM5U5fpCCAaeUwiHqNU84g0_3oi1HDLBTTqWJ-Z7n6L9DyiDvXC6WDLa-fi-4QCDPClPjBOUMhqHHBZMp3KE0mF8jc-qYwjN6fA1dme4GZmkVAK98UxiSCKsZvPEdajLj0moigqgYL_i4tCvh9muUb1Pb7KHQCPUYt42bVqRorN_0Llrvx6hWum2G60kvFarUlMoT3XShDan2VfcLxG4IPsIW7301hoI57jlecLA38gkfo0RxachTqq_iTMrKJe3W-FuvMt38Kj-L_mAv-svz8MGtcPYP) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Ports the sublinear Python solution mentioned by @CommandMaster.

```
⊞υＮ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔⦃⦄η
```

Set up a dictionary to cache calculated results.

```
Ｆυ
```

Loop over the values that need to be calculated.

```
Ｆ¬§ηι«
```

Verify that this value hasn't actually been calculated.

```
≔ιζ≔²ε≔÷ιεδ≔⟦⟧κＷ›δ¹«≔⊕÷ιδλ¿§ηδ≧⁺×⁻λε⊖⊗§ηδζ⊞κδ≔λε≔÷ιλδ»
```

Try to calculate the result for this value, but if any dependent values haven't yet been calculated, collect them in a list.

```
¿κＦ⊞Ｏκι⊞υλ
```

If there were any dependent values that haven't yet been calculated then add them for processing and add the current value for reprocessing.

```
§≔ηι÷⁺⁻×ιιζε²
```

Otherwise actually calculate the result for the current value.

```
»Ｉ§η⊟υ
```

Output the result for the initial value, which is always the last value to be calculated.

Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @JonathanAllan.

Comment: Like my comment under Value Ink's answer, I think you could start with `z=i` and square `i` avoiding the `Decremented(i)` - [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZK9bsIwFIWlbuQZOlwx2ZKRClMlJtRIFQM0qrohhpBciIVxIv_Qqogn6cJQ1D5Tn6Z2nIgg4cW6dvzdc-7J129WpCorU3E6na1ZDx7_7u4TqwtiGUxlZc3c7laoCKXjaKI130hyODIoXLkuFRBLod7npSETM5U5fpCCAaeUwiHqNU84g0_3oi1HDLBTTqWJ-Z7n6L9DyiDvXC6WDLa-fi-4QCDPClPjBOUMhqHHBZMp3KE0mF8jc-qYwjN6fA1dme4GZmkVAK98UxiSCKsZvPEdajLj0moigqgYL_i4tCvh9muUb1Pb7KHQCPUYt42bVqRorN_0Llrvx6hWum2G60kvFarUlMoT3XShDan2VfcLxG4IPsIW7301hoI57jlecLA38gkfo0RxachTqq_iTMrKJe3W-FuvMt38Kj-L_mAv-svz8MGtcPYP)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>104</s> 100 bytes

Ports the algorithm at https://oeis.org/A002088. -4 bytes from Jonathan Allan.

```ruby
A=->n,r=({0=>0}){r[c=n]||(k=n/i=2
(j=n/k+1;c+=(j-i).*2*A[k,r]-1;k=n/i=j)while k>1
r[n]=(n*n-c+i)/2)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN1McbXXt8nSKbDWqDWztDGo1q4uik23zYmtqNLJt8_QzbY24NLKAjGxtQ-tkbVuNLN1MTT0tIy3H6GydolhdQ2uIqizN8ozMnFSFbDtDrqLovFhbjTytPN1k7UxNfSPNWohdawtKS4oVHKMNDYAgFiIGcwcA)

Comment: Could you start with `c=n` and end with `(n*n-c+i)/2` for -2 bytes?

Comment: @JonathanAllan good catch. This also let me wrap the assignment inside the cache lookup for an extra -2.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES12), 75 bytes

Adapted from the Python code provided on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002088).

```javascript
f=(n,j=2,K)=>f[n]||=n>j?f(K=n/j|0)*(j+=J=~(n/K))-j/2+f(n,-J):n&&(n*~-n+j)/2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU87DoJAEO09xRSE7MggiH_NYGUjRzAkGmQ1GzKb-KkAL2JjoYfyNmLQ5r3i5f3uT7H7_PF4XS_an74TzUrIcEQJcqw3klYVS2yWWiUsgalC7Crj8ZpvSoIE0TdB5OnG469xLq6rpHvzxTMYRL9IWWxCgj5BRDAgGBKMCMYEE4IpwayRvnLYwg__FKadnran1S47KgGOIbNytkXeK-xBbXfKKaVGYHDKZgLWW8RF2_o_9AE)

#### Statistics

Assuming the cache is cleared after each call to `f`:

| \$n\$ | total number of calls |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 |
| 100 | 193 |
| 1000 | 1407 |
| 10000 | 9111 |
| 100000 | 55009 |

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 161 bytes

Adapted from the Python code provided on [A002088](https://oeis.org/A002088)

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NDoIwEITvPEXVyy4/QeqtTX0RYwzUEiGwmlLqgfDsWMA5fNnMTHbXjoNblnEwTJf6ZZ5CfOxbP/pS27cQuyej022f7lFNrAYSzYVjdg2cOuOgHx3T6cp2o0cF55SnlHOU31fTGeavxVpllaLcJ4XUiYIqazEGHtfgMStQtqqSPuSVnIFioOBlOmkx5/MS7vZlQ4BsiljQusuaYewcU@Gj4hyEcos@tiHX0QGO03xM/62QzcsP)(TIO has no `cached` crate, you need to run it locally.)

```rust
use cached::proc_macro::cached;
#[cached]
fn f(n:i32)->i32{let(mut c,mut j,mut v)=(0,2,n/2);while v>1{let b=n/v+1;c+=(b-j)*(2*f(v)-1);j=b;v=n/b;}(n*(n-1)-c+j)/2}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVKxboMwEN35imuGyCQkAbpEpiB169IpH1Ah6hSIcSJslCHi29OzMSm07g3G4r27e3d@bSfV/d5JBlJ9UlqcOWeFqs5CUvqWy/I9vySeJ1XbFQpewzAO93u4eYBR5EXJKFjWS/UcB4BHFni951XNhf/iHwUIdiU@bDI4MH60v3VwpqDp1FAS0rEmpSYhefAMvq2EZK0iYQDhBHs0s1V6g6AU2/uLKbLUTST2DkBQLdaIwe9ES5OrojSk7dDOJAp/QtFxODeMLFsmO658SDMYrsGM9KGBed5sXBw1TP6Fa4Tj/@FThLiAHdR/Odey4kwzMogcAsYydWxLIHMNUeIkFrBOgSB1A7UPKyDxymxH7@UU4QYh8t2ZeoA6dmM/6h2E3jn0sGFMI0LLEKYzHihQK9u5ljV5R2sbEdhCDtED4LmljIZCS6GdmrwSZDTF@CS59WA6unHm4NkMlmq2GIUYlnRpK6G4eCKLW7@YSO3v928)

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct A002088 {
    cache: HashMap<i32, i32>,
}

impl A002088 {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut cache = HashMap::new();
        cache.insert(0, 0);
        A002088 { cache }
    }

    fn get(&mut self, n: i32) -> i32 {
        match self.cache.get(&n) {
            Some(&result) => result,
            _ => {
                let mut c = 0;
                let mut j = 2;
                let mut k1 = n / j;
                while k1 > 1 {
                    let j2 = n / k1 + 1;
                    c += (j2 - j) * (2*self.get(k1) - 1);
                    j = j2;
                    k1 = n / j2;
                }
                let result = (n * (n - 1) - c + j) / 2;
                self.cache.insert(n, result);
                result
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a002088 = A002088::new();
    let result = a002088.get(10000);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the golfed version need the cache to make it run in sublinear time?

Comment: @Neil Thanks for your comment, I have corrected it.